# generate multiple custom blocks from a single api call

Tags: theming, 8, blocks, plugins

I have created a custom module that generates a single custom block based on content retrieved from a remote API. The content is currently displayed in a single contiguous block above the main content.

It works great, however, I am now being asked to split up the custom block content on the page. Essentially, I need to move some of the content into a sidebar and some into a smaller block at the top of the page.

The simple way to do this I guess is to create 2-3 custom blocks through the plugin system and then place them in the desired regions I create on the page templates. The problem with this is that each block would be calling out to the remote api so I would go from a single API call to 3 or even more on the same page. The remote API we are using just returns the entire set of content so I would be loading the same thing 3 or more times.

What I would really like to be able to do is keep my existing block class (in whatever form) and pass that same single API call to 3 seperate templates that can be placed as three separate blocks.

How do I do this?

Alternatively, is is there some way to generate the API call through a function in the `.theme` file in my theme (abandoning my custom module completely) and then just pass the variables directly to the page rather than going through the block system? I could also live with that though i am not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What I would really like to be able to do is keep my existing block
>   class (in whatever form) and pass that same single API call to 3
>   seperate templates that can be placed as three separate blocks. How do
>   I do this?

This is possible. Add a configuration option to the block class in `blockForm()` and then use this option in `build()` to change the content and template. Then place the block three times and choose for each instance a different option. To avoid calling the remote API three times in one request use `drupal_static()`.

> Alternatively, is is there some way to generate the API call through a
>   function in the .theme file in my theme (abandoning my custom module
>   completely) and then just pass the variables directly to the page
>   rather than going through the block system?

This is no problem. You can put three variables in `mytheme_preprocess_page()` and use them directly in `page.html.twig`.

Think about caching. You can cache the remote API call with `\Drupal::cache('data')->set()` with a certain expire time. In a block this is not necessary, you can set a cache max-age and as long the block stays in the cache the remote API is not called.